# Rescue system/Live bootable from systemd-boot

Tags: systemd, live-usb, livecd, systemd-boot

I am looking for a distro able to Live boot-up directly from systemd-boot for rescue system purposes.
Basically is a:

1. Live CD/USB
2. with some rescue tools, such as partitioning tools, etc.
3. bootable from *systemd-boot*

I do not want to install the rescue system on my disk because **a)** I have only one disk (it's a laptop) **b)** it will make difficult to operate/fix the main OS, which is on the same disk

---

*sometimes, after an edit of mine, a software upgrade, a system corruption, etc. my main OS (Arch Linux) is broken;*

Answer (score 0):

System Rescue Cd - I use it for client OS repairs. You can also add to it.

Works for Linux and Windows. I highly recommend it. Has everything you asked for, and then some.

SystemRescueCd is a Linux system rescue disk available as a bootable CD-ROM or USB stick for administrating or repairing your system and data after a crash. It aims to provide an easy way to carry out admin tasks on your computer, such as creating and editing the hard disk partitions. It comes with a lot of Linux system utilities such as GParted, fsarchiver, filesystem tools and basic tools (editors, midnight commander, network tools). It can be used for both Linux and Windows computers, and on desktops as well as servers. This rescue system requires no installation as it can be booted from a CD/DVD drive or USB stick, but it can be installed on the hard disk if you wish. The kernel supports all important file systems (ext3/ext4, xfs, btrfs, reiserfs, jfs, vfat, ntfs), as well as network filesystems such as Samba and NFS.

Comment: I used to use SRCD but it doesn't (or I am not able to) boot from *systemd-boot*

Comment: Hi Rhett, and welcome to U&L! Just a quick note on links to product/software: please note whether you are affiliated with the product/software. If you're just a happy user, say so. If you're involved with the project, please also say so. Otherwise, you run the risk of being seen as a [spammer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). Thank you!

Comment: @mattia.b89,
I understand that you need this booted from systemd-boot. The image can be installed and partitioned onto a hard-drive. Thus, giving you an option once you have the loader screen on.

Comment: I do not want to install on my only disk (because it will make difficult during operations to handle with the disk itself!); I clarified the OP.

Comment: you could also host the image on an FTP.

Comment: I need a local solution because it is a **rescue** system, that's think to worst situation: you just have your PC, no external HD/USB, no internet, no Ethernet connection...